# c++ how to implement a switch between class members

Tags: c++

I am very new to c++ so I am trying to get a feeling of how to do things the right way in c++. I am having a class that uses one of two members. which one gets determined at instantiation. It looks something like

```
main() {
    shared_pointer<A> a = make_shared<A>(); 
    if ( checkSomething ) { 
        a->setB(make_shared<B>()); 
    } else {
        a->setC(make_shared<C>()); 
    }
    a->doStuff();

class A {
    public:
        doStuff() {

        /*here I want to do something like call 
        m_b->doStuff() if this pointer is set and m_c->doStuff() if 
        that pointer is set.*/

       }

        setB( B* p ) { m_b = p; }
        setC( C* p ) { m_c = p; }
        B* m_b;
        C* m_c;
    }
}
B and C are some classes with doStuff() member function
```

There are many members like doStuff. Ideally I would avoid checking for nullptr in each of them. What is the best/most efficient/fastest way to create a switch between those two members?

Is there a way to use a static pointer so that I have a member

```
static **int m_switch;
```

and do something like

```
m_switch = condition ? &m_b : &m_c;
```

and call

```
*m_switch->doStuff();
```

Does the compiler here also replace the extra pointer hop because it is a static?

Is there any other smart way to do those switches?

Comment: do classes `B` and `C` have a common base class? or do they just happen to both have a `doStuff()` member function?

Comment: they just happen do have that member. cant use inheritance here

Comment: "Can't use inheritance" why? That's what you do to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm actually very confused by your `main()`. Is `b` of type `A` or `shared_ptr<A>` because you create it as a shared_ptr but use it like A. And are the members pointers or shared pointers? your class says pointer but your main says shared_ptr

Comment: Do _all_ the functions that you want to wrap have the same name and arguments between the `B` and `C` classes?

Comment: @tadman I cant modify the classes B and C and they are not part of a common base

Comment: @vu1p3n0x sorry for the confusion. edited it, hope it s clearer now

Comment: @ paddy yes, they do

Comment: If you have access to a C++ 17 compiler (probably not, but who knows) or Boost, you could probably use a variant containing <B, C> to help with the problem.

Comment: If you have the option, you could create an interface, `class I`, and make classes `D` and `E` that extend and implement the interface from `B` and `C`. That way you can use both members as an `I*`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x not sure I follow you. would you mind posting a solution with a small example?

Comment: I was going to post a "strategy" object from design patterns, where A has an internal object which handles doStuff, and that object can be constructed with B, C, neither, maybe both?  You'd have to write a separate class for each strategy, though.  You have to write a strategy for neither because it's that or check for nullptr anyway, which you said you don't want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, class `A` would be an *interface* class, which both `B` and `C` would inherit and implement.  But it sounds like you cannot do this for whatever reason.

Since you want to emulate this, you can start by making the interface:

```
class A_interface
{
public:
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
    virtual void doThings() = 0;
    virtual void doBeDoBeDo() = 0;
};
```

And then you make a template wrapper:

```
template< class T >
class A : public A_interface
{
public:
   void doStuff() override { target.doStuff(); }
   void doThings() override { target.doThings(); }
   void doBeDoBeDo() override { target.doBeDoBeDo(); }

private:
    T target;
};
```

This essentially does half of what your own example class `A` was trying to do, but now you can use a common interface.  All you need to do is construct the correct templated version you want:

```
std::shared_ptr<A_interface> a;

if( checkSomething ) {
    a = std::make_shared<A<B>>();
} else {
    a = std::make_shared<A<C>>();
}

a->doStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no one-size-fits-all solution for your problem. What to use depends on your particular problem. A few possible answers:

- Interfaces
- Strategy Pattern
- Pointers (to hold a function or class which implements doStuff)

An interface is like a contract. Any class which inherits from the interface must implement its members. For instance,

```
class IDoesStuff
{
public:
    virtual ~IDoesStuff() {};
    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
};
```

Can now be used by other classes:

```
class Foo : public IDoesStuff
{
public:
    virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        // ....
    }
};

class Bar : public IDoesStuff
{
public:
    virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        // ....
    }
};
```

And now, in general, one may do:

```
Foo foo;
IDoesStuff *stuffDoer= &foo;

stuffDoer->doStuff();
```

This can be used in *your* particular use case as follows:

```
class A
{
    IDoesStuff *stuffDoer; // Initialize this at some point.

public:
    void doStuff() { stuffDoer->doStuff(); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both members implement a common interface to use them similarly. But in order to do that, you need to define the interface and relay the calls to the B and C classes.

```
// existing classes
class B
{
public:
  void doStuff() { std::cout << "B"; }
};

class C
{
public:
  void doStuff() { std::cout << "C"; }
};

// define your interface
class I
{
public:
  virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};

// new classes
class D : public B, public I
{
public:
  void doStuff() override { B::doStuff(); }
};

class E : public C, public I
{
public:
  void doStuff() override { C::doStuff(); }
};

// your A class
class A
{
public:
  D* b = nullptr; // now type D
  E* c = nullptr; // now type E

  // your toggle
  I* getActive()
  {
    if (b)
      return b;
    else
      return c;
  }

  // simple doStuff() function
  void doStuff()
  {
    getActive()->doStuff();
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  if (true)
    a.b = new D; // need to initialize as D
  else
    a.c = new E; // need to initialize as E

  a.doStuff(); // prints B
}
```

But typing this up made me realize that defining `D` and `E` could get really tiresome and against what you're trying to save. However, you can define a template to create them like @paddy has done.

Answer (score 1):

First you must change your memebr variables `m_b` and `m_c` to `std::shared_ptr`.

Add a member variable of type `std::function(void())` to hold the target function you want to call. In your sample it is `do_stuf`.

In your setter functions you can bind target function to your `std::function` and in `do_stuf` just call `std::function`.

(You need a C++11 compiler)

```
class B
{
public:
    void doStuff() 
    {
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    void doStuff()
    {
    }
};

class A 
{
public:
    void doStuff() 
    {
        m_target_function();
    }

    void setB(std::shared_ptr<B> p)
    {
        m_b = p;

        m_target_function = std::bind(&B::doStuff, m_b.get());
    }
    void setC(std::shared_ptr<C> p)
    {
        m_c = p;

        m_target_function = std::bind(&C::doStuff, m_c.get());
    }

    std::shared_ptr<B> m_b;
    std::shared_ptr<C> m_c;

    std::function<void()> m_target_function;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();

    bool use_B = false;

    if (use_B) 
    {
        a->setB(std::make_shared<B>());
    }
    else 
    {
        a->setC(std::make_shared<C>());
    }

    a->doStuff();
}
```

Comment: thanks, that looks interesting... Thanks for the answer